# Android : Upload Image to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, file-upload

I want to upload an image file into mysql database on Android Mobile Programming, but I've some problem with it. Here's my code:

My code on Eclipse:

```
private void uploadFile() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String nama = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
    Bundle fieldresults = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    Filepath = fieldresults.getString("bitmap");

    Bitmap bitmapOrg= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Filepath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
    ArrayList nameValuePairs = new
    ArrayList();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filename",Filepath));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_user",nama));
    try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new
    HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/BloodGlucose/uploadImage.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

and my PHP code:

```
    <?php
include_once("koneksi.php");

$username = $_REQUEST['username_user'];


$hasil = mysql_query("select * from login"); 

$base = $_REQUEST['image'];
$filename = $_ReQUEST['filename']
$buffer=base64_decode($base);
$path = "img/".$filename.".jpg";
$handle = fopen($path, 'wb');
$numbytes = fwrite($handle, $buffer);
fclose($handle);
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db_bloodglucose");

$sql = "UPDATE login SET file = '" . $path . "' Where username_user = $username;
$r=mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

The problem is the file didn't show in my database (mysql), anyone can help me? thanks before

best regards

Comment: $_ReQUEST['filename'] not a reason to fail but you have a lower case e here. It should be $_REQUEST['filename'] :-)

Comment: also what errors are you getting? Are you certain you have a db connection? also i cant see where you are executing your sql?

Comment: I've tried it, but the image still dind't show, i wonder if i've been missing somethings on my code, btw the file is in the device, pict library (emulator)

Comment: there's no error, it just that the file didn't show on mysql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $sql looks wrong, try:

```
$sql = "UPDATE login SET file = '$path' WHERE username_user = '$username'";
$r = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: also just so you know the mysql_ functions are all now depricated http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: I've change the code, but the result is still the same, btw in mysql i put file as LONGBLOB type, i wonder if the error is on my android code?

Comment: you need to work out if the sql query is even executing before anything

Comment: well, when i check on my foler "img" the file has been uploaded there, and the problem now is the database is not updated, is there something missing? :(

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
$sql = "UPDATE login SET file = '" . $path . "' Where username_user = $username; $r=mysql_query($sql);
```

should read

```
$sql = "UPDATE login SET file = '" . $path . "' Where username_user = " . $username; $r=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: it still didn't work, hmmm, i wonder is there's something missing on my android code?